# What is wrong in "mapping" URLs to Rails actions with this form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, action, routes

In 'app/views/users/*reset.html.erb*' file I have this code:

```
<%= form_tag( send_reset_users_path, :method => :post ) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
    <%= submit_tag("Send") %>
<% end %>
```

In 'app/controllers/*users_controller.rb*' I have this code:

```
  def reset
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # reset.html.erb
    end
  end

  def send_reset
    ...
  end
```

In 'config/*routes.rb*' I have this code:

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'reset'
      get 'send_reset'
    end
  end
```

When I submit the form I get the error: "No route matches "/users/send_reset"" (browser URL becomes '.../users/send_reset'). **What is wrong?** How can I "map" URLs to Rails actions?

P.S.: I think the problem is in "config/routes.rb"...

Comment: Does your 'reset' path work? If so, try:

    collection do
      get 'reset', 'send_reset'
    end

I think there's something whack in route parsing right now that causes this to fail on some edge case that I've yet to figure out. I've seen these changes work - hopefully someone will come along and clarify.

Comment: Yes, my 'reset' path ('reset_pjt_users_path' -> URL '.../pjt_users/reset') works.

Comment: Not sure, buy try either switching the order of the two or removing the underscore from send_reset, just to make sure rails is not trying to interpret the "send_" part as one of "new_" or "edit_". If either works, it's some sort of naming conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is here `:method => :post` and `get 'send_reset'`, in my opinion you are trying to POST parameters when your conntroller expect GET method

Answer (score 3):

You routes.rb declares the `send_reset` route as only available via get. You have to write `post 'send_reset'`:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'reset'
    post 'send_reset'
  end
end
```