# How can I use a method action like the 'update', 'create' or 'destroy' actions (from scaffold)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, action, routes

I made [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479404/) changes appropriately:

Now in 'app/controllers/*users_controller.rb*' I have this code:

```
def reset
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # reset.html.erb
    end
end

def send_reset
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.errors.empty?
            ...
        else
            format.html { render :action => 'reset' }
        end
    end
end
```

Now in 'config/routes.rb' I have this code:

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'reset'
      post 'reset'
      get 'send_reset'
      post 'send_reset'
    end
  end
```

If I submit the form ('app/views/users/reset.html.erb') related to [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479404/)

```
<%= form_tag( send_reset_users_path, :method => :post ) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
    <%= submit_tag("Send") %>
<% end %>
```

the browser URL become '*.../users/send_reset*' but I want '*.../users/reset*' (I think the problem is around the 'format.html { render :action => 'reset' }' code that does not render correctly the action) or, maybe, the route.

**In few words I aim to use the 'send_reset' action like I use, for example, the 'update', 'create' or 'destroy' actions (from scaffold), in my case that is without creating the 'app/views/users/send_reset.html.erb' file but just calling the action method to handle my issue.** How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Rails URL scheme is

```
:host/:controller/:action/:id
```

Rename your controller action from

```
def send_reset
end
```

to

```
def reset
end
```

and rename the views and routes to match this change.

However you are already using reset for get and send_reset for Post but you want them to be the same just do different things if you ask for the page or send a form POST.

```
def reset
   case request.method
   when :post
       # send them an email
       # redirect_to :somewhere_else
   else # :get, :put, :delete
       # render the view with the recovery form
   end
end
```

Comment: Renaming I will have two action methods with the same name in 'app/controllers/users_controller.rb'. This is a correct way?

Comment: I overlooked that. So what you want is different functionality from the same action based on HTTP request type. I will correct my answer.

Comment: "So what you want is different functionality from the same action based on HTTP request" : is this the common way that RoR uses to route 'update', 'create' or 'destroy' actions (from scaffold)?

Comment: The rails 3 way frowns upon it. It was an early rails 2ism. A better Rails 3 way might be to submit your form to send_reset via ajax and the user would never see it.

Comment: I tried your code (case request.method ...), but when I submit the form it goes always through the 'else' condition, even I have set the ':method => :post'.

Comment: in the controller puts request.method.inspect. They must have changed it in rails 3. it used to be a Symbol as shown

Comment: "Inspecting" show me that it is all ok (GET and POST). Only the "case" statement seems do not work. It is the Symbol: you have to insert "POST" instead of ':post'.

Comment: request.get? and request.post? should work

the switch case is cleaner. puts request.method.class. Its probably not a symbol anymore.